# Can I have random colors when the user hovers over each "keyboard" button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

I've seen examples with regular  links, where the color of the linking text will change to random colors each time the user hovers over it with the mouse, but can I do that with my keyboard buttons? I'm trying to add more features to my hangman game and I'd like to have random colors appear whenever the user hovers over the letter buttons. And if anyone knows of any good reference pages that explains this, that would be great!

```
//loads everything in onload function when page loads
window.onload = function () {
    //array of alphabet letters to create keyboard UI with
    var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
        'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's',
        't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

    //different topics that player can guess from
    var categories;    

    //the chosen or selected category (chosen randomly)     
    var chosenCategory;     
    var getHint;    

    //the chosen word      
    var word;              
    var guess;

    //stored guesses            
    var guesses = [ ];      
    var lives; 

    //counts number of correct guesses            
    var counter; 

    //number of spaces ('-') in word          
    var space;              

    //getting elements by id and assigning them to variables
    var showLives = document.getElementById("lives");
    var getHint = document.getElementById("hint");
    var showClue = document.getElementById("clue");

    //create alphabet letter keyboard buttons
    var keyboard = function () {
        myButtons = document.getElementById('keyboard');
        letters = document.createElement('ul');

        for (var i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
            letters.id = 'alphabet';
            list = document.createElement('li');
            list.id = 'letter';
            list.innerHTML = alphabet[i];
            check();
            myButtons.appendChild(letters);
            letters.appendChild(list);
        }
    }

    //choosing a category
    var selectCat = function () {
        if (chosenCategory === categories[0]) {
            categoryName.innerHTML = "The chosen category is cities";
        } else if (chosenCategory === categories[1]) {
            categoryName.innerHTML = "The chosen category is films";
        } else if (chosenCategory === categories[2]) {
            categoryName.innerHTML = "The chosen category is food";
        }
    }

    //create the hidden word in underscores
    result = function () {
        wordHolder = document.getElementById('hiddenWord');
        correct = document.createElement('ul');

        for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            correct.setAttribute('id', 'hiddenWord');
            guess = document.createElement('li');
            guess.setAttribute('class', 'guess');

            if (word[i] === "-") {
                guess.innerHTML = "-";
                space = 1;
            } else {
                guess.innerHTML = "_";
            }

            guesses.push(guess);
            wordHolder.appendChild(correct);
            correct.appendChild(guess);
        }
    }

    //displaying player's lives
    comments = function () {
        showLives.innerHTML = "You have " + lives + " lives";

        if (lives < 1) {
            showLives.innerHTML = "Game Over";
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < guesses.length; i++) {
            if (counter + space === guesses.length) {
                showLives.innerHTML = "You Win!";
            }
        }
    }

    //function to perform the drawing action for the hangman figure
    var animate = function () {
        var drawMe = lives ;
        drawArray[drawMe]();
    }

    //hangman
    canvas =  function(){
        myStickman = document.getElementById("stickman");
        context = myStickman.getContext('2d');
        context.beginPath();
        context.strokeStyle = "#6F706F";
        context.lineWidth = 2;
    };

    head = function(){
        myStickman = document.getElementById("stickman");
        context = myStickman.getContext('2d');
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(60, 25, 15, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      context.fillStyle = '#CDFCFF';
      context.fill();
      context.lineWidth = 2;
      context.strokeStyle = '#6F706F';
        context.stroke();

      //left eye
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(53, 28, 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      context.fillStyle = '#6F706F';
      context.fill();
      context.stroke();

      //right eye
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(64, 25, 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      context.fillStyle = '#6F706F';
      context.fill();
      context.stroke();
    }

    torso = function() {
      //positioning torso behind head
      context.globalCompositeOperation='destination-over';
      context.beginPath();
      context.rect(56, 30, 20, 40);
      context.fillStyle = '#6F706F';
      context.fill();
      context.stroke();
    }

    draw = function($pathFromx, $pathFromy, $pathTox, $pathToy) {
        context.moveTo($pathFromx, $pathFromy);
        context.lineTo($pathTox, $pathToy);
        context.stroke(); 
    }

    frame1 = function() {
        draw (0, 150, 190, 150);
    };

    frame2 = function() {
        draw (10, 0, 10, 600);
    };

    frame3 = function() {
        draw (0, 5, 70, 5);
    };

    frame4 = function() {
        draw (60, 5, 60, 15);
    };

    rightArm = function() {
        draw (76, 45, 94, 50);
    };

    leftArm = function() {
        draw (58, 45, 40, 50);
    };

    rightLeg = function() {
        draw (75, 70, 77, 90);
    };

    leftLeg = function() {
        draw (60, 70, 58, 90);
    };

    drawArray = [rightLeg, leftLeg, rightArm, leftArm,  torso,  head, frame4, frame3, frame2, frame1]; 


    //checking if keyboard button is clicked and performs correct action
    check = function () {
        list.onclick = function () {
            var geuss = (this.innerHTML);
            this.setAttribute("class", "active");
            this.onclick = null;

            for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
                if (word[i] === geuss) {
                    guesses[i].innerHTML = geuss;
                    counter += 1;
                } 
            }
            var j = (word.indexOf(geuss));

            if (j === -1) {
                lives -= 1;
                comments();
                animate();
            } else {
                comments();
            }
        }
    }

    //gameplay
    play = function () {
        //categories (cities, films, food)
        categories = [
            ["new-york-city", "los-angeles", "london", "tokyo", "brussels", "shanghai", "beijing", "paris", "vancouver", "jakarta"],
            ["harry-potter", "finding-nemo", "jaws", "charlie-and-the-chocolate-factory", "the-breakfast-club", "spirited-away", "up", "toy-story", "forrest-gump", "the-shining"],
            ["sushi", "gelato", "banana", "chocolate", "strawberry", "sandwich", "grapes", "cheese-stick", "rice", "burrito"]
        ];

        chosenCategory = categories[Math.floor(Math.random() * categories.length)];
        word = chosenCategory[Math.floor(Math.random() * chosenCategory.length)];
        word = word.replace(/\s/g, "-");
        keyboard();

        guesses = [ ];
        lives = 10;
        counter = 0;
        space = 0;
        result();
        comments();
        selectCat();
        canvas();
    }

    play();

    //giving a hint
    hint.onclick = function() {
        hints = [
            ["Skyscraper wonderland", "Starry night", "Historic clock tower", "Neon and futuristic", "Chocolate lovers", "Global financial hub", "The Forbidden City", "Vintage romance", "Shivers up your spine", "Capital of an island"],
            ["Wizards and magic", "Lost fish", "Great white shark", "Chocolate river", "1980's classic", "Anime", "Balloon home", "Talking toys", "RUN", "Here's Johnny!"],
            ["Raw", "Italian dessert", "Also a type of slug", "Solid and liquid", "Fondue please", "Many layers", "Make wine", "Stringy", "Too small to count", "Wrap it up"]
        ];

        var categoryIndex = categories.indexOf(chosenCategory);
        var hintIndex = chosenCategory.indexOf(word);
        showClue.innerHTML = "Clue: " +  hints [categoryIndex][hintIndex];
    };

    //resetting the game
    document.getElementById('reset').onclick = function() {
        correct.parentNode.removeChild(correct);
        letters.parentNode.removeChild(letters);
        showClue.innerHTML = "";
        context.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
        play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Too much information. Details of the hangman's game logic have little to do with the question - and the code was posted in another recent question as well. Please read help center pages on how to ask questions and providing a minimal complete and verifiable example of attempted code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create random color, I think the easiest way will be to generate 3 random numbers between `0` and `255` (the range of RGB colors) and use them as values of `rgb`.
Here is a simple example of how you can get and apply random RGB color:

```js
// Get element
const target = document.getElementById('target');
// Add event listener to catch `mouseover` events
target.addEventListener('mouseover', colorTarget);

function colorTarget() {
  // Apply new random rgb color as background
  target.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${getRandomRGBNumber()},${getRandomRGBNumber()},${getRandomRGBNumber()})`;
}

function getRandomRGBNumber() {
  // Generate random number between 0 and 255. Pay attention, that we use `256`, not `255`
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
}
```

```css
#target {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px black solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it change the background of the entire div though? Is there a way to target the individual keyboard buttons? (which have "<li>" tags)

Comment: @Karen, sure, you can choose any target you like, it's just an example. And you can change the `color` instead of `background-color`, depends on your needs